# Why do we use Struts2 UI tags instead of basic html tags? What are the differences?

Tags: html, struts2, struts-tags

I am new to Struts2 and don't understand why we use UI tags instead of simple HTML ones. for example

```
<s:form action="ActionA">
  <s:textfield name="username"></s:textfield>
  <s:textfield name="password"></s:textfield>
  <s:submit name="submit" value="submit"></s:submit>
</s:form>

<form action="ActionA" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username"/>
  <input type="text" name="password"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

both perform similar functions. 
What I want to know is can i use simple html tag `<input type="text" name="username"/>` instead of `<s:textfield name="username"></s:textfield>`. and i would also like to know the difference between these two tags while performing validation.

Comment: What kind of validation do you mean?

Comment: @RomanC like password field should be at least 8 characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we use struts tags and not the old HTML tags , what difference does it bring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905528/why-do-we-use-struts-tags-and-not-the-old-html-tags-what-difference-does-it-br)

Comment: @AleksandrM yes sorry but i didnt understand that post

Comment: @ShameerM Without struts tags you can't do a client-side validation.

Comment: oh. okay. and can i use css with these strut tags?

Comment: What exactly you haven't understood?

Comment: @ShameerM Of course you can, try `cssStyle`.

Comment: @AleksandrM that when i convert my html tags to struts2 tag the css styles that are attached to the input box doesnt work.

Comment: @AleksandrM I understood that post, but I was surprised why the accepted and upvoted three times  post doesn't answer a simple question?

Comment: And *the simple question* is?

Comment: You don't have any styles in your example.

Comment: @AleksandrM `Why do we use struts tags and not the old HTML tags` I suppose. This question a bit different because OP is asking about UI tags thus narrowing to the set of struts tags.

Comment: @RomanC i have already built the css with html tags but when i change the <input type="text"> to <s:textfield> the css doesnt work.

Comment: @ShameerM Of course it doesn't work but it's a different question that has already answered several times.

Comment: @RomanC so i thought maybe if both rthese tags are pretty much similar i can use the html tags instead of struts2 tags

Comment: @ShameerM It depends what are you trying to do, you said you need to use struts tags for validation, right? And I want to get how do you do it.

Comment: @RomanC yes and i also need to get the values from database into the textfield.

Comment: @RomanC It *does* answer the question, and this one. The UI tags are the only ones under discussion-most S2 tags don't emit HTML, they're functional. There's no HTML iterator, for example. "The old HTML tags", which both questions reference, cover... well, HTML tags.

Comment: @DaveNewton Voted to close as duplicate, but should vote as off-topic.

Comment: @ShameerM There's a lot of databases in the world, but you didn't specify anyone, and you want  to get the values from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use normal HTML tags like  in JSP pages while using Struts but, If we use the struts tags, we get certain advantages like validation messages, automatic form fill-up etc.
If we use plain old HTML tags, we have to resort to scriptlets to get the values out of the form bean and into the html fields. The html tags work with the Struts framework to automagically populate html fields from your form bean fields and this results in JSPs that are cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: for scriptlets, removing them a big deal.